# HTML5 default error message placement display inconsistencies in two monitors

Tags: html, forms, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have an HTML5 form that is using the required element to validate some fields. The error messages display correctly on my 15" MacBook Pro. I have the laptop connected to a second monitor (Dell 24" LCD display). When I drag the browser to the Dell monitor and try to submit the form to see the error messages, the error bubbles no longer display underneath the correct fields. They display way above the form. I'm attaching screenshot of the displaying of the errors. I have never seen this issue before.

[image]

[image]

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Did you try refreshing the page?

Comment: yes, I did several hard refresh and clear the cache

Comment: Seems so strange because your laptop is the thing that is rendering the page, your display isn't. Very curious what it could be, sorry I really don't have a clue what could be wrong.